# Nodejs version dependency for PM2 versions

Tags: node.js, pm2

I need to upgrade PM2 version and i am using nodejs 0.10.32. Is there a way to figure out which latest PM2 version is compatible with nodejs 0.10.32 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [`package.json`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/package.json), it says `node >= 0.10`. As it's still a popular version, PM2 will probably stick to that.

Notes: Node.js 0.10 will be maintained [until October 2016](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/blob/master/schedule.png) ([roadmap](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS)), after that, modules might leave this version away, and hosts will upgrade.